# Svm Implementation in java - 1/0 classification

Tags: java, algorithm, svm

I have done SVM using 1/-1 classification.

i.e. by checking sign of decision function `wTrans * X - gamma`

```
if(decfun<0)
   setclasslabel to -1
else
   setclasslabel to 1
```

What about in 1/0 classification.

Is that the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, its a same thing.
In your mentioned SVM classification ,you are classifying data into two classes (1/-1) i.e you are just setting them label as 1 or -1.Main concept is to classify data into two classes and label them, so instead of -1 u can label 0 to that class.

```
    if(decfun<0)
   setclasslabel to 0
else
   setclasslabel to 1
```